# Is there a way to speed up the Save method with PIL?

Tags: python, image, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, amazon-sagemaker

I have an API that saves an the image to S3 bucket and returns the S3 URL but the saving part of the PIL image is slow. Here is a snippet of code:

```
from PIL import Image
import io
import boto3

BUCKET = ''
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def convert_fn(args):
  pil_image = Image.open(args['path']).convert('RGBA')
  .
  .
  .
  in_mem_file = io.BytesIO()
  pil_image.save(in_mem_file, format='PNG') #<--- This takes too long
  in_mem_file.seek(0)
  s3.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
      in_mem_file,
      BUCKET,
      'outputs/{}.png'.format(args['save_name']),
      ExtraArgs={
          'ACL': 'public-read',
          'ContentType':'image/png'
      }
                               )

  return json.dumps({"Image saved in": "https://{}.s3.amazonaws.com/outputs/{}.png".format(BUCKET, args['save_name'])})
```

How can I speed up the upload?, Would it be easier to return the bytes?

The `Image.save` method is the most time consuming part of my script. I want to increase the performance of my app and I'm thinking that returning as a stream of bytes may be the fastest way to return the image.

Comment: `Image.getdata()` will return you the values of the pixels. You can then send this values to wherever you want.

Comment: Please click [edit] and try to improve your question. It is unclear what you actually want to send, where from, where to and why your current method is too slow. You are also supposed to show a [mcve]. Thank you.

Comment: If you are *"returning"* data from a function in the same process, the answer will be very different from if you are returning a result from a subprocess and different yet again if you are returning data via a socket across a low-bandwidth, high-latency network.

Comment: I edited the post and added some of the code I have. Right now the return function is a Json, this can change

Comment: The answer to this question depends on what web framework you're using for the API. If you were using Flask, I would give a different answer than if you were using Django.

Comment: But the general answer is that you return the bytes from the BytesIO object, and also set the Content-Type header so the browser knows to expect an image.

Comment: Sorry, it's still unclear to me what the issue is. You say you have a function *"that outputs images"* and show something that sends a PNG to S3. I presume that's the output. Then you say you want to speed up the return, which is a JSON-encoded copy of the bucket URL, I think. So do you want to speed up writing the PNG or JSON-encoding the URL? You say you know which part takes longest but don't show timings? Have you tried writing JPEGs? Why do you think a stream will be quicker? A stream of what?

Comment: @NickODell How did you work out it was flask or django? ‍♂️ I see neither of those tagged or indicated? The question must be mighty unclear.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I haven't worked it out - hence the request for more information.

Comment: Re-edited the post

Comment: I'm not using flask nor Django, I'm using AWS SageMaker to create an endpoint

Answer (score 2):

Compressing image data to PNG takes time - CPU time. There might be  a better performant lib to that than PIL, but you'd have to interface it with Python, and it still would take sometime.

"Returning bytes" make no sense - you either want to have image files saved on S3 or don't. And the "bytes" will only represent an image as long as they are properly encoded into an image file, unless you have code to compose back an image from raw bytes.

For speeding this up, you could either create an AWS lambda project that will take the unencoded array, generate the png file and save it to S3 in an async mode, or, easier, you might try saving the image in an uncompressed format, that will spare you from the CPU time to compress PNG: try saving it as a `.tga` or `.bmp` file instead of a `.png`, but expect final files to be 10 to 30 times larger than the equivalent .PNGs.

Also, it is not clear from the code if this is in a web-api view, and you'd like to speedup the API return, and it would be ok if the image would be generated and uploaded in background after the API returns.

In that case, *there are ways* to improve the responsivity of your app, but we need to have the "web code": i.e. which framework you are using, the view function itself, and the calling to the function presented here.

Comment: Thank you! saving as `.bmp` and `.tga` is faster. In this case I don't care much about the size of the image.

Answer (score 2):

In `PIL.Image.save` when saving PNG there is an argument called `compression_level` with a `compression_level=0` we can create faster savings at the cost of no compression. [Docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#png)